# How can i check whether the filename exist in specific folder

Tags: sql-server

I have the following code to update document path field but i like to check first if the file name is exist on the specified folder or not. if the file exist i would like to update the field with the path otherwise skip the update

My code looks shown below

```
  use WITESTCO
  update [WITESTCO].[dbo].[WIITEMX] 
  set [docPath]='\\ABC-SERVER\Data\ABC PRODUCTION\DRAWING\2500000 - 2599999 WHL ASSY\PDF\'+[WITESTCO].[dbo].[WIITEMX].[itemId]+'.pdf' FROM [WITESTCO].[dbo].[WIITEMX] where itemId like '2500%' or itemId like '2501%'
```

Comment: you could write a `SQLCLR` function which does simple `public static bool Exists(
 string path
)`

Answer (score 1):

I bet this function will work under normal circumstances.

```
master.dbo.XP_FileExist
```

I know it will work on the local file system of the SQL instance, however, UNC filenames may or may not work. I have not tested.

Comment: i tried this `declare @result as int
declare @path as nvarchar(50)

--set your path
set @path= '\\ABC-SERVER\Data\ABC PRODUCTION\DRAWING\2500000 - 2599999 WHL ASSY\PDF\200964.pdf'

 EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist @path, @result OUTPUT

 if @result=1 
    print 'found'
 else
    print 'not found'` and i get file not found

Comment: oh may be datatype more than 50 char

Comment: i replaced the @path = `set @path= '\\ABC-SERVER\Data\ABC PRODUCTION\DRAWING\2500000 - 2599999 WHL ASSY\PDF\'+[WITESTCO].[dbo].[WIITEMX].[itemId]+'.pdf' ` but i get `Multi part identifier [WITESTCO].[dbo].[WIITEMX].[itemId] could not be bound` error

Comment: You can't inline a database object in a SET statement like you are doing. You have to use a proper sql statement for that.

Comment: thanks what do you mean by proper sql statement? how can i update that?

Comment: Never mind, I just realized that your query was an UPDATE. It should be ok.